# NoSuchMethodError java.lang.reflect.Method org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getInterfaceMethodIfPossible(java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.Class)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a project that JSF works for which I wanted to integrate spring security through the following modifications:

**Add dependencies in pom.xml:**
**(Updated)**

```
<dependencies>
  
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.15</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
    

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>        

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.9.1</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSF Dependencies -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>       
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.20</version>
    </dependency>       
    
    <!-- JSP Library -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
        
    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.30</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.48</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>font-awesome</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Primefaces Version 5 -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext -->
    <!-- Library used to export Primefaces Datatable to pdf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
   
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-taglibs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

            
</dependencies>
```

**Added SecurityConfig class:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
 
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
 
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }
     
     
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());     
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**", "/resources/**", "/index.jsp", "/login.jsf", "/pages/public/**","/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login.jsf").loginProcessingUrl("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").failureUrl("/login.jsf?error=true")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/views/home.jsf");
        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/login.jsf");
        // not needed as JSF 2.2 is implicitly protected against CSRF
        http.csrf().disable();
    }
 
}
```

While executing, the following error occurred:

> WARN
> [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]
> (ServerService Thread Pool -- 84) Exception encountered during context
> initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name
> 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
> 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException:
> Expression parsing failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.reflect.Method
> org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.getInterfaceMethodIfPossible(java.lang.reflect.Method,
> java.lang.Class)'

Thanks for the help.

Comment: NoSuchMethod means you have a missmatch in your dependencies, the selected versions you have chosen does not work worh the rest of your dependencies. This is why you ise the spring parent pom to ensure that the versions match. We have no idea what dependencies you have, but you should read the first chapter of the spring documentation that talks about the spring parent pom, why you should use it and how to implement it. Thats the first thing you always should do when using spring

Comment: @Toerktumlare, thanks for answering, i just updated the post with all the dependencies used by the project.

Comment: Please read what i wrote, i have no idea what dependencies that work with what other dependencies. That is defined in the spring parent pom and you should implement it. Read what a parent pom is, read what the spring parent pom is. Stop declaring versions and implement the parent pom.

Comment: What makes you think mixing Spring 5.3.9, 5.3.15, 5.3.18 and 5.3.19 jars are a good idea? Make sure that jars have the same version. I strongly suggest to use the latest 5.3.x version (and put that in a property so you only have the version in 1 location). The method it is complaining about was added in 5.3.16, so your mixture of versions is the issue here. Basically never mix jars from different versions of a framework (regardless of the framework) as that is trouble waiting to happen.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Thank you for the good quality of your answer, the error was related to the different versions used in the project. it is corrected with the proposal you suggested and the error is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found for those who have the same problem. The error is related to using of different versions of spring-core, spring-webmvc and spring-orm libraries.

It is for this reason that it is preferable to use the generalized method to specify the versions of the libraries, this is done with the  tag of the pom.xml file.

Here is the modified version of the pom.xml file:

```
<properties>
    <springframework.version>5.3.19</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>5.6.3</springsecurity.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
 
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
            
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to mix versions of a library/framework, generally the versions should match. If you don't match the versions you might (and will) run into compatibility issues.

Further more I would suggest to use the so called Bill Of Materials files to make your life easier. Those include all needed dependencies, and require the definition of a single version.

Finally it is better to use a property to define the version and use that, so that everything is in a single place.

```xml
<properties>
    <springframework.version>5.3.20</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>5.6.3</springsecurity.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
      <version>${springframework.version}</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
            
</dependencies>
```

With the BOM included you can remove the `<version>` from your regular dependencies, as those will now be managed by the BOM. You could also cleanup your dependencies a little `spring-tx` is already included in `spring-orm` and `spring-core` basically in everything. `spring-security-core` is also already pulled in by the other `spring-security-*` dependencies.

Now you can manage your dependencies with 1 single property/version and they should always match.

Comment: A graceful and beautiful intervention, important ideas, thank you.